# Getting data from the server and using ng-options in select control is failing to show options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this my HTML

```
<div ng-app="timeTable" ng-controller="addCoursesCtrl">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewCourse()">Add New Course</button><br/><br/> 
            <fieldset ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="choice.type" ng-options="s for s in coursetoAdd">
                            <option value="{{s.shortCut}}">{{s.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Course Name" name="" class="form-control" ng-model="choice.course"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
            </fieldset>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="convertAndSend()">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

this the js

```
var timeTable = angular.module("timeTable",[]);
timeTable.controller("addCoursesCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.choices = [{ course: '', type: '' }];
    $scope.coursetoAdd ;

    $http.get("/Semster/getSuggtedCourses").then(function (response) {
        $scope.coursetoAdd = response.data;
    });
    $scope.addNewCourse = function () {
        var newITemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({ course: '', type: '' });
    };
    $scope.convertAndSend = function () {
        var asJson = angular.toJson($scope.choices);
        console.log(asJson);
        $http.post('/Semster/Add', asJson);
    };

});
```

this code bind an object {"course":...,"type":....} every time you click on add course ,and add input field dynamically , my problem is with select control,I'm getting the data from server and use it with ng-optin ,but all it shows it's just [object Object] in select option not the real value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data returned from getSuggestedCourses is an array of objects, the ng-options selector:

```
s for s in courseToAdd
```

will bind s to each object in the array. You need to bind to the fields in the object like this

```
s.value as s.name for s in courseToAdd
```

Comment: the get method return json data,but this works only for s.name , I need to bind more than element

Comment: What is the structure of the returned json?